# Why did adapter.Fill suddenly stop working to fill my data table in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, iis

I have an application that queries a database and returns the results in a datatable. Last night, I was able to use the application without any issues. This morning, the application suddenly stopped working. I have not made any changes to the application since testing it last night. I opened Visual Studio and started to debug the application. As I am debugging the application, it's getting tripped up in the following code:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string query, string Connection = "SqlConnection")
{
    SqlConnection connSql = CreateConnection(Connection);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connSql);
    DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
    connSql.Open();
    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(myDataTable);
    }
    finally
    {
        connSql.Close();
    }
    return myDataTable;
}
```

Specifically, adapter.Fill simply will not fill myDataTable. I don't get any errors, mind you, just an empty datatable that is returned.

Troubleshooting I've done:

1. I checked the connection used and had no issues logging into SQL
   Server with the username and password provided.
2. I copied and pasted
   the value from "query" into SQL Server and ran the query without any
   issues either.
3. I deleted my temporary internet files and cleared my cache.
4. I tried viewing the application through a different
   computer.

Given that this was working yesterday and now it is not today (without me making any changes), what could have caused this issue? I am working in a Windows Domain environment. I'm not sure what additional troubleshooting I can do!

Comment: Edit your `c#` code and add a `catch` block. Check what that error message is, and if that does not help you, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59773640/edit) your question and add the error message to your question.

Comment: There will almost certainly be an error. Catch the exception and post that. Could be the server is offline or anything.

Comment: Check what changes happened between yesterday and today. Did the database tables structure change? The database users changed? What about the sql server logins (they are two separate but related things)? Network/firewall changes?

Comment: You can use the SQL profiler to check what query is sent to the SQL if you had debugged it and there is no exception. And please check SQL server name and database name - I've a lot such errors when there are several test dbs on the server and getting latest source code version overwrites the `app.config` with wrong connection string.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very common code to use SqlClient except for `CreateConnection` method.

Change it to : `new SqlConnection()`

Comment: This sould be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Believe this is due to the connection been opened after the attempt to use the adapter command.

```
    Datatable dt = new Datatable();
using (SqlConnection connection = 
            new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
                queryString, connection);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8